# Sqlite attribute unique count

Tags: sqlite

Thats not the original code(obviuosly) but it shows pretty simple the problem

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES(
Name STRING,
ID INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO NAMES (Name,ID)
VALUES (BOB,1)
INSERT INTO NAMES (Name,ID)
VALUES (BOB,2)
INSERT INTO NAMES (Name,ID)
VALUES (TOM,3)
INSERT INTO NAMES (Name,ID)
VALUES (JAN,4)
```

I want from that table the number off occurences of each Name (in this case: 2 1 1)
and i searched already a lot and probably i need a combination of COUNT and Unique but i have no idea how to write that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple `GROUP BY` query to get this result:

```
SELECT
    Name, COUNT(*) AS name_count
FROM NAMES
GROUP BY
    Name
```